# Group all other values in array for each value - MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Suppose you have a collection in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
{names:['James','Mark','Anne','Philip']}{names:['Mark','Vladimir','Greg']}{names:['Greg','Anne','Philip']}
```

How do you sort out a collection like the one above so that you get a collection with each document being for one person and with an field 'co-workers' with all the names of people that this person was in each document from the collection above? So given the example above, a collection like this:

```
{name:'James',co-workers:['Mark','Anne','Philip','Vladimir','Greg']},{name:'Mark',co-workers:['James','Anne','Philip','Vladimir','Greg']},{name:'Greg',co-workers:['Mark','Vladimir','Anne','Philip']}
```

...etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by following these steps :

- Duplicate names field as colleagues
- Unwind by name
- Remove current name from colleagues list
- Group by name
- Merge the different colleagues lists

Here's how to do this in mongo :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      colleagues: "$names"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$names"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      colleagues: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$colleagues",
          "as": "colleague",
          "cond": {
            $ne: [
              "$$colleague",
              "$names"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$names",
      colleagues: {
        "$push": "$colleagues"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      colleagues: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$colleagues",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UVw0RkaAQET)

Answer (score 0):

I just grouped by "set" identifier.

```
# GENEREATE TEST DATAFRAME OF ALL NAMES BY SET IDENTIFIER
allNames = dict( c1 = {'names':['James','Mark','Anne','Philip']},
          c2 = {'names':['Mark','Vladimir','Greg']},
          c3 = {'names':['Greg','Anne','Philip']})
arr = []
for s,d in allNames.items():
    arr += [dict(col = s, nm = n) for n in d['names']]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
print("\nORIGINAL COLLECTIONS by set id's c#")
print(df)

print("\nCOLLECTIONS by names of co-workers with same")

# Create dict of co-workers for each worker
for n in df.nm.unique():
    cList = df[df.nm == n].col
    print(n, list(df[df.col.isin(list(cList))].nm))

ORIGINAL COLLECTIONS by set id's c#
  col        nm
0  c1     James
1  c1      Mark
2  c1      Anne
3  c1    Philip
4  c2      Mark
5  c2  Vladimir
6  c2      Greg
7  c3      Greg
8  c3      Anne
9  c3    Philip

COLLECTIONS by names of co-workers with same
James ['James', 'Mark', 'Anne', 'Philip']
Mark ['James', 'Mark', 'Anne', 'Philip', 'Mark', 'Vladimir', 'Greg']
Anne ['James', 'Mark', 'Anne', 'Philip', 'Greg', 'Anne', 'Philip']
Philip ['James', 'Mark', 'Anne', 'Philip', 'Greg', 'Anne', 'Philip']
Vladimir ['Mark', 'Vladimir', 'Greg']
Greg ['Mark', 'Vladimir', 'Greg', 'Greg', 'Anne', 'Philip']
```

Comment: thank you, however this is done with pandas dataframes, not with MongoDB